# Reordering and grouping existing array

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a JSON array as formatted below, generated in PHP using a foreach loop to generate an array from an WP ACF group (see below). I seem to be unable to use GROUP BY when getting the particular fields for this ACF group, hence the double entry for name (with different times) as shown.

```
[
    {"name":"Location1","gigs": 
        {"start":"16:30","end":"21:15","title":"TestTitle1","class":"fri"}
    },
    {"name":"Location 2","gigs":
        {"start":"15:00","end":"19:00","title":"TestTitle2","class":"fri"}
    },
    {"name":"Location 1","gigs":
        {"start":"21:00","end":"22:00","title":"TestTitle3","class":"fri"}
    }
]
```

This JSON array should ideally be formatted as follows, the difference being the entries with the same name/location should be combined as shown below.

```
[
    {
        "name":"Location1",
        "gigs": [
            {"start":"16:30","end":"21:15","title":"TestTitle1","class":"fri"},
            {"start":"21:00","end":"22:00","title":"TestTitle3","class":"fri"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name":"Location 2",
        "gigs": [
            {"start":"15:00","end":"19:00","title":"TestTitle2","class":"fri"}
        ]
    }
]
```

I've tried several array merge/combine/sort/etc functions available in PHP, but can't get it to output as intended.

Here's the code generating the array/JSON output:

```
function get_shows( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    $parameters = $request->get_params();

    switch($parameters[1]) {
        case 'fri':
            $show_day = 'fri';
            $show_select_day = '20170901';
            break;
        case 'sat':
            $show_day = 'sat';
            $show_select_day = '20170902';
            break;
        case 'sun':
            $show_day = 'sun';
            $show_select_day = '20170903';
            break;
    }

    $showDates   = array();
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'post_type'         => 'performances',
        'meta_key'          => 'per_date',
        'meta_value'        => $show_select_day
    );

    $shows = get_posts( $args );

    if ( ! empty( $shows ) ) {
        $i = 0;
        foreach( $shows as $show ) {
            $acf = get_fields($show->ID);
            $show_loc = get_the_title(get_field('per_location',$show->ID));
            $show_title = get_the_title(get_field('per_busker',$show->ID));

            if ( ! empty( $acf ) ) {
                $showDates[$i]['name'] = $show_loc;
                $showDates[$i]['gigs']['start']     = date("H:i", strtotime($acf['per_time_start']));
                $showDates[$i]['gigs']['end']   = date("H:i", strtotime($acf['per_time_end']));
                $showDates[$i]['gigs']['title']     = $show_title;
                $showDates[$i]['gigs']['class']     = $show_day;

            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
   return   $showDates;
}
```

Any suggestions to get the output in the correct format would be more than welcome. Thanks much!

Comment: *"I have a JSON array"* -- there is no such thing like *"JSON array"*. [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json) is text. Nothing more. It can be decoded to restore the data structure used to create it and, depending on the second argument passed to [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), the result can be made entirely of arrays or it it may contain objects instead of associative arrays. However, the question doesn't seem to be about JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try follwong solution. I have change your key `Location1` to `Location 1` because `Location1 != Location 1`

```
$json_data = '[
    {"name":"Location 1","gigs": 
        {"start":"16:30","end":"21:15","title":"TestTitle1","class":"fri"}
    },
    {"name":"Location 2","gigs":
        {"start":"15:00","end":"19:00","title":"TestTitle2","class":"fri"}
    },
    {"name":"Location 1","gigs":
        {"start":"21:00","end":"22:00","title":"TestTitle3","class":"fri"}
    }
]';
$arr = json_decode($json_data,true);
$new_array = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
  if(isset($new_array[$value['name']]))
      $new_array[$value['name']]['gigs'][] = $value['gigs'];
    else{
      $new_array[$value['name']]['name'] = $value['name'];
      $new_array[$value['name']]['gigs'][] = $value['gigs'];
    }
}
$new_array = array_values($new_array); //to remove keys
echo json_encode($new_array);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/SO3oP)